Infected marigold leaves
My daughter brought home a marigold for Mother's day and it had these light brown spots on all the leaves at on the bottom so I cut the entire arm of leaves off instead of individual leaves. I did this to two arms of leaves and two tips leaves as well. Did I harm my marigold or will it grow back?

Can you add a photo of the plant please
